# html audio tag, play while loading

Tags: javascript, html

I have an audio tag

```
<audio id="soundContainer" preload="metadata" loop></audio>
```

where I load sources from javascript, which works fine 
but sources are songs, which means they are 5+mb 
and they only start playing after fully loaded(downloaded)

```
document.getElementById("soundContainer").setAttribute('src', _path );
document.getElementById("soundContainer").load();
document.getElementById("soundContainer").play();
```

here I need help.
is there a way to play audio on load/while loading
hope I explained fairly and thanks in advance.

Comment: It does not wait until entire audio is downloaded. Use `oncanplay` which alerts that audio can be played..

Comment: yes, thanks, I tried that...
but oncanplay triggers when it's ready to play and this means it has finished loading/downloading, still music starts to play minute or so after.

Comment: @Amber are you able to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually already play audio while loading. Audio starts playing once you get enough data. Try to cap network bandwidth in Chrome and check out the network activity.

If you want to negate even this tiny delay, you can just use two sound containers. One for playing and another one for pre-loading content. 
Keep in mind, that currently playing audio container will be still downloading audio data while playing and consume network bandwidth.

```
<html>
<script>
var currentSound = 0;
var sounds = [
 "one.mp3",
 "two.mp3",
 "three.mp3"
]

function switchAudio() {
  var notPlaying = document.querySelector("audio:not(.playing)");
  var nowPlaying = document.querySelector("audio.playing");
  if(nowPlaying!==null) {
    nowPlaying.pause();
    nowPlaying.className="";
  }
  notPlaying.className="playing";
  notPlaying.play();
}

function nextTrack() {
  var notPlaying = document.querySelector("audio:not(.playing)");
  notPlaying.setAttribute('src', sounds[currentSound]);
  currentSound=(currentSound + 1) % sounds.length;
  notPlaying.load();
  notPlaying.oncanplay = switchAudio;
}

</script>
<body>
  <audio preload="metadata" loop></audio>
  <audio preload="metadata" loop></audio>
  <button type="button" onclick="nextTrack()">next track</button>

</body>
</html>
```